# Remove Circle Icon in Notifications

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, oneplus-x

A new icon appeared in my notifications today. It looks like [Remove Circle from the Material icons](https://material.io/icons/), except with an additional outline.

There's no info/action when I try to press on it; if I try to drag the notification section down, the icon disappears until the section collapses back.

Rebooting did not remove it.

It looks almost like the left-most icon on the right side of this screenshot ([source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/169961/what-does-this-notification-icon-mean)):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That icon certainly looks like a do not disturb icon (DND).

You can turn it off from quick settings or in Settings >> Sounds  >> DND

Comment: In my android nougat device, thats the same exact icon that appears when DND is enabled

Comment: This is almost the right answer. While there's no DND setting in Settings >> Sounds, I saw that I couldn't change the ringer volume, and I had to use the notifications "switch" on my phone hardware (toggles between all/priority/silent). Thanks for the help.

Comment: anytime :) glad you fixed it